# Android 4.2.2 removes all files after reset/restart

Tags: android, linux, android-kernel

I have a Set top box based on Allwinner A20 chip.

I have cross compiled mono for a20 chip and I copied all files to root directory and it works fine. but when I restart of reset set top box all files are removed automatically. any one have a solution of it so that my mono files persists permanently. Android 4.2.2 is runs in STB.

Answer (score 1):

Root directory in android aka '`/`' is **ramdisk**.

Ramdisk like the name indicated its a space located in the ram and will be reloaded from its source after reboot.

If you want to put something persistently into the system, push it to `/system/`